# How many geodatabases per ArcGIS Server license?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, license

I need to create and authorize a new ESRI ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase. Our organization has an existing ArcGIS Server license that has already authorized one ESRI ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase. Will I be able to specify the existing ArcGIS Server authorization file to create another enterprise geodatabase within the same organization and network? I would just try except that someone else administers the ArcGIS Server and we are still in the planning stage.

I understand that we will need ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced (not Basic) to Create an Enterprise geodatabase.

ArcGIS for Server is version 10.0. Our ArcGIS for Desktop Standard is version 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are running on the same RDBMS Server; you don't have a number constraint. You will have to acquire additional licenses based on number of machines or number of CPU/Cores.